# How to figure out Linear transformation of this linear combination?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, linear-transformations

[image]
The title basically. I have NO idea how I am supposed to solve this question! I know that the process is to use U1 U2 U3 and W as a linear combination to solve it, but I only ever get scalars a and b, but only those 2 don't really help anything. Setting it up in a matrix and rref'ing doesn't work either! I've asked like 8 different people for help, but no one I know is able to help. I'm at my whits end trying to figure this out, so any help would be really appreciated. Let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: Do you know how to express $W$ as a linear combination of $U_1, U_2, U_3$?

Comment: thats setting it up in a matrix right?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

This is straightforward.   You just need to express $W$ as a linear combination of the $U_i$.  Then you can use linearity and the values of $T$ on the $U_i$.

First you have the following system: $$\begin {pmatrix}1\quad-3\quad 2\\-1\quad 3\quad 1\\2\quad-6\quad 5\end {pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end {pmatrix}=\begin {pmatrix}-7\\-2\\-17\end {pmatrix}$$

Once you get $a,b$ and $c$, the answer is $$T(W)=aT(U_1)+bT(U_2)+cT(U_3)$$.

Comment: How do I get a, b, and c though?  I mean, I know it will make (a-3b+2c = -7), but how would I solve that?

Comment: Ok, to solve the system row-reduce the augmented matrix.   Do you want me to show you?

Comment: I do know that, but the problem is that 'c' is always 0.

Comment: That's fine.   Why is that a problem?

Comment: Because when I use the formula, the answer Is always wrong

Comment: Ok, then almost certainly a careless mistake.

Comment: But I've used the same method you are describing? Is there something there I'm missing? Because I get <-45, 6> when the answer is <75, 16>

Comment: $(-1,0,-3)$ works

Comment: i got (-1, -3, 0)

Comment: Let $(a,b,c)=(-1,0,-3)$.  Then you get $(75,16)$.

Comment: You made a mistake. $a=-1,b=0,c=-3$ works though.

Comment: Can you show me how you row reduced it? I keep getting (-1,-3, 0)

Comment: Actually,  when I noticed the second column was a multiple of the first,  I just did it in my head. Set $b=0$.

Comment: So are columns that are multiples of each other automatically 0?

Comment: Yeah kind of.  The point is you don't need both.   You can also set $a=0$.  See it?  There's more than one solution.

Comment: ooooooooooohhhhh I get it now, you'd just use one or the other to row reduce

Comment: The matrix is singular, so as long as there's one solution (and there is), there's more than one.   You'll learn more about the theory as you go along.   There's only one answer to the problem though.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This was killing me for the longest time.

Comment: My pleasure.....